# nodejs synchronization read large file line by line?

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems, mojibake

I have a large file (utf8). I know `fs.createReadStream` can create stream to read a large file, but not synchronized. So i try to use `fs.readSync`, but read text is broken like `"迈�"`.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var util = require('util');
var textPath = __dirname + '/people-daily.txt';   
var fd = fs.openSync(textPath, "r");
var text = fs.readSync(fd, 4, 0, "utf8");
console.log(util.inspect(text, true, null));
```

Comment: Are you sure that the file is encoded with utf8?

Comment: yes, Unicode(UTF-8) and Unix(LF)

Comment: I think you mean "synchronous" rather than "synchronized".

Comment: I posted a solution to a similar question for parsing a very large file, using a stream, synchronous. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010915/parsing-huge-logfiles-in-node-js-read-in-line-by-line/23695940#23695940

Answer (score 12):

For large files, `readFileSync` can be inconvenient, as it loads the whole file in memory. A different synchronous approach is to iteratively call `readSync`, reading small bits of data at a time, and processing the lines as they come. The following bit of code implements this approach and synchronously processes one line at a time from the file 'test.txt':

```
var fs = require('fs');
var filename = 'test.txt'

var fd = fs.openSync(filename, 'r');
var bufferSize = 1024;
var buffer = new Buffer(bufferSize);

var leftOver = '';
var read, line, idxStart, idx;
while ((read = fs.readSync(fd, buffer, 0, bufferSize, null)) !== 0) {
  leftOver += buffer.toString('utf8', 0, read);
  idxStart = 0
  while ((idx = leftOver.indexOf("\n", idxStart)) !== -1) {
    line = leftOver.substring(idxStart, idx);
    console.log("one line read: " + line);
    idxStart = idx + 1;
  }
  leftOver = leftOver.substring(idxStart);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

use https://github.com/nacholibre/node-readlines

```
var lineByLine = require('n-readlines');
var liner = new lineByLine('./textFile.txt');

var line;
var lineNumber = 0;
while (line = liner.next()) {
    console.log('Line ' + lineNumber + ': ' + line.toString('ascii'));
    lineNumber++;
}

console.log('end of line reached');
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [readFileSync](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.12/api/fs.html#fs.readFileSync):

> fs.readFileSync(filename, [encoding]) Synchronous version of
>   fs.readFile. Returns the contents of the filename.
>
> If encoding is specified then this function returns a string.
>   Otherwise it returns a buffer.

On a side note, since you are using node, I'd recommend using asynchronous functions.

Comment: @nroe, then why are you asking for a synchronous read? Of course that won't work with a large file.

Comment: @Tom, nroe likely wishes to be able to receive the lines as return values to the read calls. Some code implementing this is available in [this blog post](http://blog.jaeckel.com/2010/03/i-tried-to-find-example-on-using-node.html) (not mine).

Answer (score 2):

I built a simpler version JB Kohn's answer that uses split() on the buffer. It works on the larger files I tried.

```
/*
 * Synchronously call fn(text, lineNum) on each line read from file descriptor fd.
 */
function forEachLine (fd, fn) {
    var bufSize = 64 * 1024;
    var buf = new Buffer(bufSize);
    var leftOver = '';
    var lineNum = 0;
    var lines, n;

    while ((n = fs.readSync(fd, buf, 0, bufSize, null)) !== 0) {
        lines = buf.toString('utf8', 0 , n).split('\n');
        lines[0] = leftOver+lines[0];       // add leftover string from previous read
        while (lines.length > 1) {          // process all but the last line
            fn(lines.shift(), lineNum);
            lineNum++;
        }
        leftOver = lines.shift();           // save last line fragment (may be '')
    }
    if (leftOver) {                         // process any remaining line
        fn(leftOver, lineNum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe change `split('\n')` to `split(/\r?\n/)` to support possible windows line endings, as well?

Answer (score 1):

two potential problems,

1. 3bytes BOM at the beginning you did not skip
2. first 4bytes cannot be well format to UTF8's chars( utf8 is not fixed length )

Answer (score 0):

Node 11 added an async iterator syntax for this.  See [a related answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43638105/how-to-get-synchronous-readline-or-simulate-it-using-async-in-nodejs/54269197#54269197)

Long story short:

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const readline = require('readline')

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(filename)
})

for await (const line of rl) {
  await processLine(line)
}
```