# Using SHA-256 with NodeJS Crypto

Tags: node.js, node-crypto

I'm trying to hash a variable in NodeJS like so:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var hash = crypto.createHash('sha256');

var code = 'bacon';

code = hash.update(code);
code = hash.digest(code);

console.log(code);
```

But looks like I have misunderstood the docs as the console.log doesn't log a hashed version of bacon but just some information about SlowBuffer.

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: What this digest does ?

Comment: Here are [examples from projects for doing md5 hashing](https://www.codota.com/code/javascript/query/crypto@@createHash+crypto@Hash@digest+crypto@Hash@update) - replace 'md5' with 'sha256' to get what you need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [node.js hash string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878682/node-js-hash-string)

Answer (score 279, accepted):

`digest` returns the hash by default in a Buffer. It takes a single parameter which allows you to tell it which encoding to use. In your code example, you incorrectly passed the encoding `bacon` to `digest`. To fix this, you need only to pass a valid encoding to the `digest(encoding)` function.

base64:

```js
const { createHash } = require('crypto');
createHash('sha256').update('bacon').digest('base64');

// nMoHAzQuJIBqn2TgjAU9yn8s2Q8QUpr46ocq+woMd9Q=
```

hex:

```js
const { createHash } = require('crypto');
createHash('sha256').update('bacon').digest('hex');

// 9cca0703342e24806a9f64e08c053dca7f2cd90f10529af8ea872afb0a0c77d4
```

Comment: See https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html

Comment: Can we follow this method in angular? I tried this in an angular project and it didn't work..

Comment: @Ish crypto is a Node module. Node is a server runtime. Assuming that you're running Angular in the browser, you'll need to use browser APIs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/digest

Comment: `var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");`
`var hmac = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(stringToBeHashed, secretKey);`
`var hash = hmac.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);` This worked for me. Thanks @mirichan

Comment: I'm not sure how this answer has so many upvotes considering the hash is wrong. the correct base64 encoded, sha256 hash of 'bacon'  is actually the one starting with "nMoHAzQuJI..." *NOT* the one starting with  "OWNjYTA3MD..."... the crypto lib is doing exactly what you are telling it.. create a hash of bacon and encode it in base64 which gives "nMoHAzQuJIBqn2TgjAU9yn8s2Q8QUpr46ocq+woMd9Q="

Comment: @masonCherry Yup. I think this would be the way:  
`createHmac('sha256', secret).update('I love cupcakes').digest('hex')`

Answer (score 7):

you can use, like this, in here create a reset token (resetToken), this token is used to create a hex version.in database, you can store hex version.

```
// Generate token
 const resetToken = crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('hex');
// Hash token and set to resetPasswordToken field
this.resetPasswordToken = crypto
    .createHash('sha256')
    .update(resetToken)
    .digest('hex');

console.log(resetToken )
```

Comment: Why hash the random bytes? Why not just generate 32 random bytes and use that as a resetToken?

Answer (score 6):

Other way:

```
const {createHash} = require('node:crypto');
const result = createHash('sha256').update("bacon").digest('hex');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

[nodejs (8) ref](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_hash)

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const hash = crypto.createHash('sha256');

hash.on('readable', () => {
    const data = hash.read();
    if (data) {
        console.log(data.toString('hex'));
        // Prints:
        //  6a2da20943931e9834fc12cfe5bb47bbd9ae43489a30726962b576f4e3993e50
    }
});

hash.write('some data to hash');
hash.end();
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the answers above, but this shows how to do multiple writes; for example if you read line-by-line from a file and then add each line to the hash computation as a separate operation.

In my example, I also trim newlines / skip empty lines (optional):

```
const {createHash} = require('crypto');

// lines: array of strings
function computeSHA256(lines) {
  const hash = createHash('sha256');
  for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    const line = lines[i].trim(); // remove leading/trailing whitespace
    if (line === '') continue; // skip empty lines
    hash.write(line); // write a single line to the buffer
  }

  return hash.digest('base64'); // returns hash as string
}
```

I use this code ensure generated lines of a file aren't edited by someone manually. To do this, I write the lines out, append a line like `sha256:<hash>` with the sha265-sum, and then, upon next run, verify the hash of those lines matches said sha265-sum.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old thread but, at this time, The [hash.digest([encoding])](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#hashdigestencoding) function accepts a `encoding` not data.

```js
        var hash = crypto.createHash('sha256');
        var code = 'bacon';
        hash.update(code);
        var digest = hash.digest();
        console.log('hex   : %s', digest.toString('hex'));
        console.log('base64: %s', digest.toString('base64'));
```

I got,

```
hex   : 9cca0703342e24806a9f64e08c053dca7f2cd90f10529af8ea872afb0a0c77d4
base64: nMoHAzQuJIBqn2TgjAU9yn8s2Q8QUpr46ocq+woMd9Q=
```