# How to Encrypt With RSA OAEP SHA-256 in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, encryption, rsa, sha, cybersource

I am trying to encrypt a card number using RSA OAEP SHA-256 format using node js. Then I am supposed to send this encrypted card number with to the exp. date and key id to Cybersource. I am given the public key in a jwk format. This includes the key_id, algorithm, etc. I have tried multiple ways, including converting the jwk key to a pem format. Have not succeeded yet.

This is the error I get when I attempt to enter an encrypted card number I created:

(node:2673) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: StatusCodeError: 400 - "{\"responseStatus\":{\"status\":400,\"reason\":\"DECRYPTION_ERROR\",\"message\":\"Cannot decrypt PAN (RsaOaep256): data hash wrong\",\"correlationId\":null,\"details\":[],\"_embedded\":{}},\"_links\":{\"self\":null,\"documentation\":[],\"next\":[]}}

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to provide a minimal code to reproduce the problem. See more details on how to post a question at this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Can you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27970431/using-sha-256-with-nodejs-crypto